# How can I make my screen locker script work?

Tags: bash, cron, gnome, screen-lock

I've been having some problems with my screenlocker program. Spent a day trying to solve it but nothing worked, so I decided to write a program that locks my screen:

```
LOCKTIME=60
lastIdleTime=0
extra=0
while [ 1 ]; do
    sound=$(pacmd list-sink-inputs | grep -c "state: RUNNING")
    idleTime=$(($(xprintidle) / 1000))
    lock=$(gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep -c " active")
    if [[ $lock != 0 ]]; then
        extra=$idleTime
    else
        if [[ $sound != 0 || $idleTime -lt $lastIdleTime ]]; then
            extra=$idleTime
        fi
        if [[ $(($idleTime - $extra)) -gt $LOCKTIME ]]; then
            gnome-screensaver-command -l
        fi
    fi
    lastIdleTime=$idleTime
    sleep 1
done
```

If I execute it manually, everything goes well. But I want to run it at startup, so I tried to use crontab and create a desktop entry at ~/.config/autostart folder. But it seems that crontab doesn't execute the program, or it executes but the script can't lock my screen, and it runs with desktop entry, but `xprintidle` doesn't update and `gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep -c " active"` returns 0 all the time, so after 60 seconds it stays locking my screen every second.

I also wrote it in python, and it doesn't work either. The only diference is that `gnome-screensaver-command -q | grep -c " active"` returns 1 all the time.

Is there a better way to execute and keep it running (and working) every startup?

Btw, I'm using Antergos with GNOME and GDM.

Comment: If you're using cron to run it at startup, try starting it as your user and not root.

Comment: Also, cron is not using the same environment (X11 display, D-Bus session, etc.)

Comment: Call your script via su and make it a login shell. Here is an example of the cronjob entry: `@reboot su - [YOURUSER] -c "[PATHTOYOURSCRIPT] &"`

Comment: @LukasIsselbächer I'm already running as my user and I tried your entry at the command line, but pacmd complains that there is no pulse audio daemon running (I think it's because of the flag --login ), and cron didn't execute it either. ephemient I know it, do you think I can do it using a desktop entry?